# 3 Watt Resistor Wattage Problem

Tags: power, resistors

I have a defective 120 Ohms 3 watt resistor that needs replacement. My place have 120 ohms with all available wattage except for 3 WATTS. I have checked online but they don't sell 120 Ohms 3 Watt. I am thinking of combining 2 or 3 resistors to get the value of 120 Ohms 3 watts. The problem is with the connection. I don't know how to do it. I have made some research but they are using formulas in their discussions which I couldn't understand. I am seeking help from anyone who could give me the right resistance, wattage and connection (series/parallel) so I can get the exact resistance value and wattage. Thank you in advance.

[image: Defective 120 ohm 3W]

Comment: 1 and 119 in series would do it. Or 2 and 118. Or 3 and 117. or 4, 45, 4 and oh wait, the doorbell

Comment: Do you have three 1 W 470 ohm on hand?

Comment: Let's say if I have 3pcs of 470 ohm 1W, how should I connect them, series or parallel?

Comment: 1W of 119 ohm connected in series? thanks!

Comment: @DonaldKwan 3x 1 W 470 \$\Omega\$ resistors in parallel is equivalent to a 3 W 157 \$\Omega\$ resistor.

Comment: It looks a little small for 3 watts. I'd double check the part if I were you.

Comment: Is there enough space for a 5 W resistor?

Comment: *"I have checked online but they don't sell 120 Ohms 3 Watt"*. Of course they do. See [here](http://uk.farnell.com/c/passive-components/resistors-fixed-value?resistance=120ohm&power-rating=3w), [here](https://www.mouser.fr/Passive-Components/Resistors/_/N-5g9n?P=1z0x6xbZ1z0wszx), and on many other places. Certainly even alibaba.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flbYrh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The left one is an obvious solution, just use a higher rating than 3 W

The other solutions using multiple resistors all add up to make a 120 Ohm, 4 W resistor which can replace a 120 Ohms 3 W resistor.

I also agree with Andy's comment, that doesn't look like a 3 W resistor unless you are a giant and have **HUGE** hands. My guess is that this is a 0.5 Watt resistor.

Comment: Thank you all for your prompt response. I should have thought of just increasing the rating to either 4-5W. Btw, the rating of 3W is written on the PCB board. This resistor works as an output of my left channel audio amplifier.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I replaced it with 120 ohm 5w and it is now working fine. More power to you. :)